# Deleting multiple lists with two conditions in python

Tags: python

I have two lists containing some image pixel values and its "measurements". I'm trying to delete items from those if it satisfies two conditions. I tried looping over it with a for loop before realizing my dumb mistake. My code is below. What could be a method to do it?

```
for i in range(100):
    delete_chance = np.random.random()
    if abs(measurements[i]) == 0.15 and delete_chance < 0.70:
        del images[i]
        del measurements[i]
```

Comment: What's the dumb mistake? Why doesn't this code work and what should it do instead?

Comment: If you just iterate over the `reversed(range(100))` instead it can actually be safe.

Comment: Whatever solution you might end up using, you should eliminate the float equal comparison. There are special function for float comparison, look it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list comprehension can help:

```
filtered_images, filtered_measurements = zip(*[(i, m) for i, m in zip(images, measurements) if math.isclose(abs(m), 0.15) and random.random() < 0.7])
```

Note we are using `math.isclose()` which has only been added to Python 3.5. If you're on older versions [you'll have to write your own `isclose()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33024979/636626).

If speed is an issue (thousands or millions of images) you can use NumPy, too:

```
images = numpy.array(images)
measurements = numpy.array(measurements)

mask = numpy.logical_and(
    numpy.random.rand(images.shape[0]) < 0.7,
    numpy.isclose(numpy.abs(measurements), 0.15)
)

filtered_measurements = measurements[mask]
filtered_images = images[mask]
```

Comment: Almost got it where I want. But this seems to, while downsampling randomly, mask all the other values. I would like to keep those values. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I don't understand what your're asking

Comment: Your numpy code produces an output that masks all the values other than abs(0.15). I want to reduce the number of abs(0.15) values, but I would like to keep all the other values which were present in the list.

Comment: You mean `removed_images = images[~mask]`?

Comment: Bingo! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try filter:

```
z = zip(*list(filter(lambda x: x[1] != 0.15 or np.random.random() >= 0.7, zip(measurements, images))))
measurements = list(z[0])
images = list(z[1])
```

Comment: You're using values from `images` as an index for `measurements`. I don't think this will work. Instead try zipping `images` and `measurements`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should never compare two floats directly, you should compare them using a function that accept a reasonable error (epsilon).

Second, first build an iterator that return `True` for whatever element you want to remove:

```
t = [np.random.random() < 0.7 and np.isclose(abs(measurements[i]), 0.15) for i in range(100)]
```

Then build a new list accordingly:

```
measurments = [m for m,b in zip(measurments,t) if not b]
images = [m for m,b in zip(images,t) if not b)]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could iterate in reversed order:

```
for i in range(99, -1, -1):
    delete_chance = np.random.random()
    if abs(measurements[i]) == 0.15 and delete_chance < 0.70:
        del images[i]
        del measurements[i]
```